# How can an uncommitted delete on a SQL (Oracle) database affect other operations?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, relational-database, rdbms

The situation is the following:

- We have an XML file from which a Java program gathers data, passing what it mines to a PL/SQL SPC that saves batches of 200 tuples in a Oracle database (in a table that I'll call TARGET)
- We are making some tests and tried to DELETE FROM TARGET;
- We forgot to COMMIT; this latest operation
- We ran the program and it consistently stalled at the 34th batch
- We noticed that we didn't commit the delete and so we did
- The program resumed it's normal operation without any further operation needed

Now, the DBA told me that the cause of the problem was the uncommitted DELETE but to my understanding an uncommitted modification simply doesn't exist on the actual database, so my doubt is that this stall can verify again due to a bug in the PL/SQL procedure.

So, my question is: **can an uncommited DELETE somehow block transactions**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updates require locks. You cannot update the same record from two transactions at the same time. One of them will have to wait for the other one to commit or rollback.

I am not 100% sure how deletes are treated in this situation, but they probably also acquire locks of some sort, if not the exact same row locks an update would take. Even if different rows are affected, there is probably a maximum number of transactions that can work on a given block (I'm reaching here...)

Comment: Thank you for explaining the concept clearly, the DBA explanation wasn't this clear.